# ceph: 370 pgs are stuck inactive for more than 300 seconds

Tags: cluster-computing, ceph

I have a small Ceph cluster. The way it is set up is described here:

https://www.theo-andreou.org/?p=1750

After a restart on the deploy node (where the ntp server is hosted) I get:

```
ceph health; ceph osd tree
HEALTH_ERR 370 pgs are stuck inactive for more than 300 seconds; 370 pgs stale; 370 pgs stuck stale; too many PGs per OSD (307 > max 300)
ID  WEIGHT   TYPE NAME       UP/DOWN REWEIGHT PRIMARY-AFFINITY
 -1 10.88989 root default                                      
 -2  0.54449     host node02                                  
  0  0.54449         osd.0      down        0          1.00000
 -3  0.54449     host node03                                  
  1  0.54449         osd.1      down        0          1.00000
 -4  0.54449     host node04                                  
  2  0.54449         osd.2      down        0          1.00000
 -5  0.54449     host node05                                  
  3  0.54449         osd.3      down        0          1.00000
 -6  0.54449     host node06                                  
  4  0.54449         osd.4      down        0          1.00000
 -7  0.54449     host node07                                  
  5  0.54449         osd.5      down        0          1.00000
 -8  0.54449     host node08                                  
  6  0.54449         osd.6      down        0          1.00000
 -9  0.54449     host node09                                  
  7  0.54449         osd.7      down        0          1.00000
-10  0.54449     host node10                                  
  8  0.54449         osd.8      down        0          1.00000
-11  0.54449     host node12                                  
  9  0.54449         osd.9      down        0          1.00000
-12  0.54449     host node13                                  
 10  0.54449         osd.10     down        0          1.00000
-13  0.54449     host node14                                  
 11  0.54449         osd.11     down        0          1.00000
-14  0.54449     host node16                                  
 12  0.54449         osd.12     down        0          1.00000
-15  0.54449     host node17                                  
 13  0.54449         osd.13     down        0          1.00000
-16  0.54449     host node18                                  
 14  0.54449         osd.14     down        0          1.00000
-17  0.54449     host node19                                  
 15  0.54449         osd.15       up  1.00000          1.00000
-18  0.54449     host node20                                  
 16  0.54449         osd.16       up  1.00000          1.00000
-19  0.54449     host node21                                  
 17  0.54449         osd.17       up  1.00000          1.00000
-20  0.54449     host node22                                  
 18  0.54449         osd.18       up  1.00000          1.00000
-21  0.54449     host node23                                  
 19  0.54449         osd.19       up  1.00000          1.00000
```

The nodes are up and ssh accessible. Is there a way to bring the system back to health?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the OSD deamon was down (even on the nodes that were reported as 'up'). After running `I=0; for ID in {02..10} {12..14} {16..23}; do   ceph-deploy osd activate node${ID}:/var/local/osd${I};   I=$((${I}+1)); done` I now have **HEALTH_OK**

A big thanks the the #ceph IRC channel!